# Why is the projection of a closed polytope closed?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

In general, projection of a closed set into a subspace does not result in a closed set. However, I was able to prove that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the projection of a closed polytope (intersection of finitely many closed half spaces) onto a 1 dimensional subspace is closed. However the proof involved induction on dimension and using the theory of linear optimization.

Is there a short topological proof of this fact? And perhaps a generalization that projection onto an m-dimensional subspace preserves closure? Intuitively imagining the shadow of a polytope, I feel it's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a property of linear maps in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not just projections.

The key result here is that the class of polyhedral sets (intersection of a finite number of closed half-spaces) is the same as the class of finitely generated sets (Rockafellar, "Convex analysis", Theorem 19.1).

To quote Rockafellar, "This classical result is an outstanding example of a fact with is completely obvious to geometric intuition, but which wields important algebraic content and is not trivial to prove".

Suppose $P$ is a polyhedral set, then there are vectors $v_1,...,v_l, d_1,....,d_m$ ($l$ or $m$ may be zero with appropriate adjustments, the $v_i$ are 'points', the $d_j$ are 'directions') such that
$P = \{ \sum_i \lambda_i v_i + \sum_j \mu_j d_j | \sum_i \lambda_i =1, \lambda_i \ge 0, \mu_i \ge 0 \}$.

Suppose $A$ is a linear operator. Then
$AP = \{\sum_i \lambda_i A v_i + \sum_j \mu_j A d_j | \sum_i \lambda_i =1, \lambda_i \ge 0, \mu_i \ge 0 \}$, hence $AP$ is finitely generated, and so is a polyhedral set, hence closed.

Comment: Did you mean to put $\lambda_i A v_i ...$ in the definition of $AP$? You actually get something suggestive of this if you treat the system of linear inequalities as a matrix and try to project the solution set, but it doesn't quite get you there. Not how I was doing it, anyway.

Comment: @LokiClock: Thanks for catching that, I meant to use $A$, not $P$. (When I looked at the problem originally I used $P$ for a projection, then realised that it works for any linear map but never updated my notes.)

Comment: The idea of the above is to use the 'interior' rather than the 'exterior' description of the polyhedral set.

Answer (score 2):

There is a purely topological way to look at this. The other proofs are probably more sensible, but I wanted to rescue the intuition about limit points.

First of all, if we're looking at a *bounded* polytope $P$, then $P$ is compact.  If $Y$ is any topological space, and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to Y$ is any continuous function, then $f(P)$ is compact as well. If $Y$ is Hausdorff, this implies that $f(P)$ is closed.

This does not immediately work for an unbounded polytope, but it can be modified to work by compactification. For instance, if $P$ is a half-space with boundary containing the origin, then we can compactify $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a closed, solid ball — by adding a point at infinity to each ray from the origin — so that $P$ extends to a solid hemisphere. Then any projection onto a subspace $\mathbb{R}^n \to V$ extends naturally to a projection of balls, so we can apply the earlier compactness argument.

Comment: I'm not familiar with compactification arguments. Can you say what theorems are being used here and what the topology on this compactified space is? Also how does your argument generalize? You specify here that P is a half space instead of a polytope.

Comment: @Mark I'm just identifying $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the interior of the open unit ball, via any homeomorphism $[0\infty) \to [0,1)$ applied to the distance to the origin.  Nothing fancy here.

Comment: @Mark Compactifying a general polytope is probably not very hard, though.  An unbounded $n$-cell can be closed off by adding an $n-1$-cell, which can be "pushed out to infinity".  All that's necessary is to ensure that these extra cells glue correctly.

Comment: We cannot show f(A intersect B) = f(A) intersect f(B) because it's not true when f is the projection onto a line.

Comment: @Mark True enough; it seems I was assuming that the union was convex.  I stand by the compactification, though.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. By the same reasoning, it would follow that projections of arbitrary closed convex cones should be closed (i.e. the result extends from finite to arbitrary intersections of closed half-spaces). But this is false: let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be the cone generated by the disk $\{(x,y,1) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, : \, (x - 1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, then the projection of $K$ onto the $xy$-plane is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, : \, x > 0\} \cup \{0\}$. How do you account for this?

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn This post is obviously quite old, but a way to make this argument rigorous could be something like this: construct a compactification compatible with the given projection via induction on the number of half-spaces.

Comment: @Slade thanks for your reply. I realise the post is quite old, but I'm just trying to point out a mistake for the benefit of future users. You did not alleviate my concerns, so I tried to pinpoint the exact mistake in your argument. I think I found it: the projection does not extend to a *continuous* map of the balls. Let $B_2^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the (Euclidean) closed unit ball, and $\mathring{B_2^n}$ its interior. Following your construction, we assume to have a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathring{B_2^n}$ which preserves directions (i.e. $0 \mapsto 0$, and [...]

Comment: [...] $v \mapsto \lambda(v) v$ for some function $\lambda : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$). Consider a concrete example: $n = 2$, and $\pi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is the projection onto the first coordinate. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $x_n = (n,n^2)$. Under the chosen homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathring{B_2^2} \subseteq B_2^2$, this sequence has a convergent subsequence (since $B_2^2$ is compact). As the homeomorphism preserves directions, the angle of this subsequence converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so the subsequence converges [...]

Comment: [...] (in $B_2^2$) to the point $(0,1)$. However, the projections of $x_n$ diverge to $+\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$, so after applying the homeomorphism $\mathbb{R} \cong (-1,1) \subseteq [-1,1]$ the sequence of projections converges to $1$. Of course, the projection of $(0,1)$ should be $0$, not $1$. In conclusion: while the projection $\pi$ is continuous as a map $\mathring{B_2^2} \to (-1,1)$, nevertheless it does not extend to a continuous map $B_2^2 \to [-1,1]$. Does this make sense, or did I misunderstand the proposed construction?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a closed polytope which has the same projection of the original solid and whose intersection with the projection space is also the projection (strictly, the projection of this intersection onto the projection space is the projection). Since the projection space takes the subspace topology, the intersection of this polytope with the projection space is also closed. The quotient topology on the projected space is given by taking cosets of the projection axis, which agrees with the topology given by the bijection sending a point in the projection space with its subspace topology to its coset by the projection axis.

Taking the minkowski sum of the polytope with the axis of projection, the union over the cosets of the polytope by the projection axis, would produce an appropriate closed set, but I don't have proof at hand that it's closed. So, you can convert the polytope to one with the same projection, which is closed, and whose intersection with the origin is identical as follows:

---

Suppose the polytope is bounded to one side of the projection surface.

Translating the polytope along the projection axis does not change its projection, by definition. Translate the solid to where it lies strictly to one side of the projection space. Reflecting the polytope across the projection axis, we see a vertex is a front vertex iff the line segment connecting it to its reflection passes through the interior to the polytope and/or its reflection.

Take the set of front vertices, and take as a translation vector the negative of one of their vector projections onto the projection axis. Translating the front vertices along the projection axis until they lie on the opposite side of the projection space from the rest of the solid, they can be separated from the back of the solid by the projection surface, and so upon all further translation we obtain a convex polytope from the intersection of the solid with the half-plane containing the back of the polytope with boundary the projection surface. The polytope's projection is unchanged by taking these variants, only its intersection with the projection surface.

In repeating this translation indefinitely, the intersection of the modified polytope with the projection surface converges to the projection: the edges which connect a vertex whose projection lies on the boundary of the projected solid to a point on the projection surface are truncations of the skewed edges of the original solid, and thus project to subsets of their projections. Hence, the vertices of the intersection become arbitrarily close to the projections of vertices on the boundary of the projection, and since the projections of edges from the polytope are edges themselves when nondegenerate, the agreement of the edges of the intersection with them is a function of the agreement of their vertices, and so on.

---

Otherwise, suppose the polytope is not bounded to one side of the projection surface.

The projection is the union of all intersections with the projection surface of translations the polytope along the projection axis. Therefore, the union of the projections of the two polytopes given by restricting the polytope to the half-spaces on either side of the projection surface is the projection of the union of these two polytopes - the original polytope. Then the previous case can be applied to determine that each half's projection is closed, which shows that their union is closed, which shows the original projection is closed.

---

I don't want to go into more detail than necessary, but you can construct polytopes from each vertex and its surroundings which have only that one vertex, a vertex's projection either lies on the boundary of or is in the interior of the projection, and is in the interior iff, moving to the vector space centered at the vertex, the origin of the analogous projection space is interior to the projection of the polytope constructed from the vertex's projection, which can be described in terms of the non-negative scalar multiples of the projections of its edges. I was working towards showing the projection was a convex polytope as well through this. I definitely prefer the approach copper.hat posted though, I don't find this definition of convex polytopes comfortable at all.

Comment: I like the geometric intuition behind this. I think there must be some modifications to deal with unbounded polytopes. In cutting away one of front vertices, you might turn an unbounded polytope into a bounded one. Otherwise it makes sense since cutting away points is the same as intersection with a closed half space which maintains closure even after infinitely many cuts.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it assumes the polytopes can be contained on either side of the projection surface. Bit of a recurring blind spot. I'll think some more about the case where that's not true. Although, if it's not bounded on either side of the projection axis, the lines through the projection surface have to all be parallel. Might could argue that makes all vertices interior to the projection.

Comment: @Mark That should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Projections are continuous functions, and continuous functions preserve limits. If a set contains all of its limit points, then the image of that set under a continuous function also contains all of its limit points. Not sure off the top of my head what the conditions are for this to hold in a general topological setting, but it sure should hold in Euclidean space.

Comment: So are you saying projections are closed functions? This is not true in general.

Comment: This is not true. The set $\{ (x,y) | y(1-|x|) \ge 1 \} \cap ([-1,1] \times \mathbb{R}^2)$ is closed but the projection onto the $x$ axis is $(-1,1)$ which is not.